# Entity framework core does not include when ToListAsync, but does with FirstOrDefaultAsync

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have a query that looks like this (Entity framework core 2.2.7):

```
        var query = from row in _entities.MyEntities
                .Include(e => e.MyEntityChildren)
                .Include(e => e.MyParent)
                .Include(e => e.MyParent2)
                .Include(e => e.MyParent3)
                .Include(e => e.MyParent4)
            where row.MyParent4.Id == "whatever" &&
                  dict.Contains(row.Id) &&
                  active.Contains(row.Status)
            select row;
```

Then I have different results based on how I execute the query:

```
var e = await query.FirstOrDefaultAsync();
```

Works correct

```
var e = await query.Distinct().ToListAsync();
```

Does not populate MyParent3. But both queries include all the other relations.

So my question is. Is this a known issue? What is the difference between first and list? And does anything know how to resolve it?

The generated sql looks the same and MyParent3 is fetched from database in both cases so I suspect it is something with the serializer. This worked in entity framework core 2.0.9

EDIT:forgot distinct!

Comment: you added "distinct" : you mean that ToListAsync alone works, but not if you use Distinct ?

Comment: Ow, I can see a potential problem with the "ToList" : it gets all the data, so maybe one of the data is causing the include to fail. 
Please provide also the actual Schema for the SQL table for MyParent3, and what is your DataBase (SqlServer ? MySql ?).

Comment: And the definition of the relevant classes, of course (`MyEntity` and `MyParent3`)

Comment: Thank you @Pac0, that could explain it. I had some trouble debugging because I had a First that worked, but then when I got the list even the first failed. (I assume because it is a reference. Let me investigate this.

Comment: If your data don't match what EF is expecting, then maybe a lot fo buggy behavior can arise. We can hardly help more without you giving the actual code, though.

Comment: `FirstOrDefaultAsync` and `Distinct()` are completely different and *can't* generate the same query - unless EF Core used client-side evaluation to pull *all* the data to the client and try to filter them there. `FirstOrDefaultAsync` is a `SELECT TOP 1 ` that returns the first matching row, no matter what it contains. `Distinct()` generates a `SELECT DISTINCT` instead that returns *multiple* rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no idea why it happens and also don't really want to post the whole project because MyEntity is e.g. Orders and MyParent3 is ShippingInformation

But, if I loop the result like this it works:

```
var result = new List<MyDomainEntity>();
foreach (var dto in query.Distinct())
{
    result.Add(GetEntity(dto));
}
```

I will just leave the result if anyone else experience this.

EDIT: I had made a naming conflict.

Comment: What does `GetEntity` do?

Comment: I is irellevant for the solution, but I just get data out of EF as dto and then my getEntity is what converts it to my domain model. But I found out that getlist always have all correctly loaded, but getlistasync does not. (oh, i shouldn't have named it List<Entiy> it should have been List<DomainEntity> or something)

Comment: That's no solution. That's essentially the same as the original code. `ToList()` iterates over the input and adds the elements to the list it returns

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos but it works. When I use ToListAsync then MyParent3 is null, and when I use ToList then MyParent3 is filled out.

Comment: Without the entities and their relations it's impossible to solve EF Core questions. There are no serializers involved, EF Core (and all ORMs) read the results using ADO readers, generate classes and fill them

Comment: @ThomasKoelle it works because it's the original code broken apart. Check [ToList](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system.core/system/linq/Enumerable.cs,329)'s source code. The queries you compare though are **very** different. The first one is a `SELECT TOP 1 ` that returns the first result only, no matter what it contains. The second is a `SELECT DISTINCT` that returns *multiple* results. They aren't the same query at all

Comment: @ThomasKoelle which EF version are you using? Unless it's EF Core 3, it's possible that EF Core used client-side evaluation or executed multiple queries to get the data. The two operators generate completely different queries.

Comment: @ThomasKoelle another possibility is that the first row returned by TOP 1 *doesn't* have a related entity. Unless you specify an ORDER BY, there's no guaranteed order and the returned row is almost random. `DISTINCT` on the other hand forces a sort and obviously changes the order of the returned results

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thank you for brainstorming! There could be something wrong in setup somewhere, but it isn't data in a row. E.g. I get 53 rows, all have MyParent4 when I get it with ToList, and all MyParent4 becomes null when I use ToListAsync. I use EF core 2.2.7, and I think it worked in 2.0.9. When I fire up profiler on SQL server then the generated SQL is the same. (It is sql server 2012)

Answer (score 1):

**Difference between first and list assuming data of (2, 3, 4, 1) from your query:**
 - Lists is similar to an array, which contains more than 1 element will get ([2, 3, 4, 1])
 - First only contains 1 element, which is the first element (2)

**As to why it is not working, my best guess is:**
 1. The format of the data obtained through your query is not able to serialize into a list, therefore there is no output there.
 2. Your first example does not have the actual data too, which will return a default item